# PHP Str replace function with special html characters

Tags: php, str-replace

My script extract span with it's attributes. I want to replace span with attributes with something else. I am using following piece of code, maybe cause of special characters it doesn't work.

```
    $tag=strtolower(str_replace("'<<span_id="ctl00_cphpagecontant_label6"><b>'","B",$tag));
```

Comment: So you want to replace the *exact* string `'<<span_id="ctl00_cphpagecontant_label6"><b>'` with `B` referenced as `$tag`?

Comment: @jensgram Yes, to replace exact string with B

Comment: In that case the above should work. Can you paste an example of `$tag`'s value before attempting the above? My gut-feeling is that the string is not *exactly* what you want to replace (`<<`, `contant` and wrapped in `'`s all seem a little weird).

Comment: @jensgram I think the value is not in $tag

`<<span_id="ctl00_cphpagecontant_lalel1"><b>job_categories</b></span>><span id="ctl00_cphPageContant_FunctionalAria"><font size="2">Consultancy</font></span></<span_id="ctl00_cphpagecontant_lalel1"><b>job_categories</b></span>>`

Comment: @jensgram I tried all but it was not working, finally I break the string into pieces and replace each separate. now trying to replace this <=""> with nothing. $tag=strtolower(str_replace("'<=\"\">'",""), $tag);

Comment: `$tag=strtolower(str_replace("'<=\"\">'", "", $tag));` (notice parenthesis moved.) But does your string contain `<="">` *in that exact sequence of characters*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Nesting quotes, ya' need to escape 'em mate!

If you have a string wrapped in `""` and would like this string to contain a literal `"` you will need some sort of method to say that "hey, I want this character here - but it's not the end of the string", that's where escaping comes in.

By prepending your character with a backslash `\` you tell the PHP interpreter just that; this character is a part of the string, it's not used to denote the end of it.

```
$tag=strtolower (
  str_replace ("'<<span_id=\"ctl00_cphpagecontant_label6\"><b>'","B",$tag)
);
```

Note: *Does the string you'd like to replace start and end with `'`? Otherwise those characters should be removed from the string.*

Comment: I tried all but it was not working, finally I break the string into pieces and replace each separate. now trying to replace this `<="">` with nothing. 

`$tag=strtolower(str_replace("'<=\"\">'",""), $tag);`